# Is it possible to use Juju on MAAS nodes not connected to Internet?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, juju, maas

At present I'm testing Ubuntu Juju with MAAS nodes, on a 12.04 server. For this I'm using Virtual Boxes.

Actually, I am wondering if it possible to deploy Juju charms on MAAS nodes which does not have any kind of access to the Internet.

For this use case, I'm thinking of a local ubuntu mirror for MAAS nodes commisioning, and locally stored Juju charms for service deployment.

Is it enough to have a fully disconnected MAAS cluster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work in theory, but many of the charms will pull in stuff from the internet when configuring, like a BZR or Git repository or something like that.

I would recommend allowing machines to be connected to the internet. If you are concerned about security, you can set up the network to do NAT or have a firewall so incoming requests can't get to the nodes, but outgoing requests can.

If you are concerned about bandwidth usage, I would set up squid or some other proxy in a transparent configuration between the virtualbox nodes and the internet. (I did this since I'm on a limited transfer connection and this worked fine).

The feature to support running disconnected has a bug report here if you want to follow along:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1215948